# Verifying tags order while parsing Stereolithography (STL) Files

Tags: java, parsing

I want to parse Stereolithography-Files (STL) which come in ASCII-Format, but I have some problems doing so.

Now, the files have to follow a certain format:

```
solid [NAME]
    facet normal [NX] [NY] [NZ]
        outer loop 
            vertex [P1X] [P1Y] [P1Z]
            vertex [P2X] [P2Y] [P2Z]
            vertex [P3X] [P3Y] [P3Z]
        endloop
    endfacet
    ... + more facet-endfacet blocks
endsolid [NAME]
```

I can read those files by using `Scanner` plus `BufferedReader`. I also have no problem to determine if the given arguments (P1X, P1Y, etc.) do exist and if they are valid or even if it is an STL-file at all.

My main problem is that I do not really know how to determine if the tags are in correct order. Right now, I can only determine, if all tags are properly closed (every opening tag has a closing tag). Here's the code for that:

```
private static boolean areTagsBalanced()
{
    HashMap<String, String> tagPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    tagPairs.put(SOLID, ENDSOLID);
    tagPairs.put(FACET, ENDFACET);
    tagPairs.put(OUTER, ENDLOOP);

    Stack<String> openingTags = new Stack<String>();
    HashSet<String> closingTags = new HashSet<String>(tagPairs.values());

    for (int i=0; i<fileContent.size(); i++)
    {
        if (tagPairs.containsKey(fileContent.get(i)))
        {
            openingTags.push(fileContent.get(i));
        }
        else if (closingTags.contains(fileContent.get(i)))
        {
            if (openingTags.isEmpty() || !fileContent.get(i).equals(tagPairs.get(openingTags.pop())))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return openingTags.isEmpty();
}
```

As you might see, the code does not care about the order in which the tags are found in the file. Maybe someone has some input for me on that one. Thanks!

P.S.:

I need to check the correct order of tags sice my code would mark this code as valid, although the order of tags is completely messed up:

```
solid
vertex
vertex 
vertex 
    facet normal
    endfacet
    outer loop 
    endloop
endsolid
```

Comment: what's wrong with your code? You are checking in the loop that every encountered closing tags is matched by the top of the opening tags stack. That's a correct algorithm to verify tags order.

Comment: For example:

    solid
    vertex
    vertex 
    vertex
    facet normal
    endfacet
    outer loop 
    endloop
    endsolid

This would come out valid, although the tags are completely messed up.

Comment: is there a list of rules which tags can be included into other? Like [DTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_definition)?

Comment: Not that I know of. All I have is what Wikipedia tells me: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) STL rules are pretty straightforward and only thing you need to check is tag parent.

There are several ways:

- setup a map to store valid parents
- make tag types an enum with method like `isValidParent(Tag name)`
- straightforward if-else method.

Map seems to be easiest one (at least while we have only one allowed parent):

```
Map<String, String> parents = new HashMap<>();
parents.put(SOLID, null);
parents.put(FACET, SOLID);
parents.put(OUTER, FACET);
parents.put(VERTEX, OUTER);
```

Then in your loop check parent for each new opening tag:

```
if (tagPairs.containsKey(fileContent.get(i))) {
    // current top of the stack is a parent for new opening tag 
    String parent = openingTags.peek(); 
    if (!parents.get(fileContent.get(i)).equals(parent)) {
        return false;
    }
    openingTags.push(fileContent.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Now that's interesting, thanks! Actually I wonder why I did not come up with somethink like that since I've done something similar already... You know... see the forest for the trees... :(

Comment: Ah, I see there is still some kind of problem with the first element (SOLID) which actually has no parent (null). Since it is the first tag and the stack is empty, therefore `String parent = openingTags.peek();` will not work.

Comment: Oh, I thought peek() will return null for an empty stack. You need an additional check for SOLID in this case.

Comment: Yeah, did that with a simple if-statement. But there is another problem :)
Actually it does recognize the first "round" of solid-facet-outer but after that (when another facet begins) the last item on top of the stack is "outer" (I left out the vertices) and since outer cannot be the parent of facet, the method returns false.

Comment: sry missed your comment. You need to remove top element of `openingTag` after corresponding `closingTag` to maintain valid state.